# In ES6, when throw is called, is the code immediately beneath the throw statement ever executed?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In node I am accustomed to handling errors with callbacks.

I'm trying to make the jump to async... await, which uses a method of error handling that I am not used to.

I am wondering, when throw is called, is the code immediately beneath the throw statement ever executed?  In other words, do I need to do this...

```
async fetch() {
    if (somethingBad) {
        throw new Error('Cannot fetch')
    } else {
        let result = await this.read(this.get('id'))
        return result
    }
}
```

...or is it enough just to do this:

```
async fetch() {
    if (somethingBad) throw new Error('Cannot fetch')
    let result = await this.read(this.get('id'))
    return result
}
```

Comment: Have you tried testing the theory?

Comment: I did, and it seems to work.  But, one likes to be sure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In ES6, when throw is called, is the code immediately beneath the throw statement ever executed?

No, it is not.  In an async function, `throw` means to immediately return a rejected promise.  It's pretty much like doing this:

```
return Promise.reject(new Error('cannot fetch'));
```

It exits your function immediately and returns a rejected promise with the reason set to whatever value you used with `throw`.

One nice thing about `async` functions is that they automatically catch exceptions and turn them into rejected promises since the contract for an `async` function is that it always returns a promise.

---

FYI, in a non-async function (e.g. just a regular function), the rest of the function is not executed either.  The function is immediately suspended.  You've thrown an exception that will propagate up the call chain until if finds an exception handler or to the top level (where it will be an unhandled exception).